# PHP date_create_from_format not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$voucherDate = 'December 22, 2015 03:43PM';
$validDate = date_create_from_format('F j, Y g:iA', $voucherDate);

echo date_format($validDate, 'Y/m/d');
```

This correctly outputs "2015/12/22" as expected. The problem I have is that when the $voucherDate variable is changed to pull from my MySQL database, the output is blank.

Basically while `echo $row['datePurchased'];` will output "December 22, 2015 03:43PM", the code above can't seem to process it the same way.

When I simply echo out the database information being received, I get exactly "December 22, 2015 03:43PM". So I don't understand why the process works flawlessly as long as I manually set the variable, but not when the variable is being set from a database. I've even tried using strval:

```
    $voucherDate = strval($row['datePurchased']);
```

To force the data into a string in case it wasn't already. This makes no difference. 
For reference here, the $row['datePurchased'] is the database data which like I've said, contains precisely the same data as what I've tried manually feeding the code.

I'm totally stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you done a `var_dump` - maybe it contains some weird characters?

Comment: @hd Thanks, I'd never used that before, and it revealed an extra space character at the beginning of the string! That seems to have solved my problem! Perfect!

Comment: @RyanVincent you're absolutely right. I'm very new to this stuff, and the database entries and created and then accessed by various parts of what is surely quite sloppy code, so this was a (supposedly) simple way to parse the date format into something I could use. I'm learning as I go, so I'll keep this in mind!  Thanks for your help!